# How can paginate for get 3200 tweets from a user?

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

I just start to learn make an application with using twitter api 1.1. I want to get 3200 tweets of an user but I couldnt find out how can I add pagination ? Please can you show me solition way ? Here is my code. I take only 198 tweets.

```
import oauth2 as oauth
import json

# Twitter API documentation
# https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1

# Get access tokens from https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/tokens-devtwittercom   
consumer_key = ''
consumer_secret = ''
access_token = ''
access_secret = ''


consumer = oauth.Consumer(key=consumer_key, secret=consumer_secret)
token = oauth.Token(key=access_token, secret=access_secret)
client = oauth.Client(consumer, token)


header, response = client.request('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=true&screen_name=username&count=500')


print len(json.loads(response))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twitter's [Working with Timelines](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/working-with-timelines) is a very nice document that explains how it works. At first glance, it would seem that there should be a normal paging scheme and there was early on. However, the amount of traffic that comes in and the fact that the most recent tweets is changing quickly makes this impractical. So, they offered since_id and max_id to ensure you get the latest tweets without duplication.

Comment: yes, I got it. But there is a problem: when I use since_id and max_id I can get only 20 tweets, so I must use a for loop, forexample I must do like that since_id:10 max_id:30 and after since_id:30 max_id:50, right?

Comment: Yes, you would use a loop. Use since_id or 3200 tweets (or 198) to tell when to stop iterating. since_id is set before the loop because it indicates the oldest tweet you already have and it doesn't change in the loop. The first iteration uses only count and subsequent iterations use count and max_id where max_id is set to the lowest id from the previous iteration. I blogged about it here too: http://geekswithblogs.net/WinAZ/archive/2012/09/02/working-with-timelines-with-linq-to-twitter.aspx

Comment: Hi again, how can I get tweets more than 3200, please can you tell me ?

Comment: According to Twitter docs, https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline, 3200 is the max.